# How to debug django with `heroku logs --tail` in detail?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, debugging, logging

I am new to Django. I've deployed my django site on Heroku.

What I would like to know is how to display logs at production environment as same as that of development environment.

Of course, I googled it but I just found tips about how to use logger, and this should be triggered by `logger.info('str')` at view, right?

what I want to achieve is:

- display traceback as same as development environment
- display `print` method at every view, without logger (I mean, without defining `logger.info` to each locations.

I know using `print` for debugging purpose at production is far from best practice, but it is okay, because I will delete it at once by using vim command after fixing all of the bugs.

I am using:

```
Django 1.11.5
Python 3.6.1
WSGI
```

Comment: Did you configure your logger ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#examples